# I need to update an alembic and keep materials

Tags: materials, linked-data, alembic

I need to import alembics in my scene and I would like to do a lots of updates of this object without losing my materials (& other datas).
For example, I have a main scene, I import an alembic, do some shading. Then, each time I modify the alembic, I need to re-assign the materials (or animation or modifiers).

I already tried to put the alembic in another file, link it and adding a library overide. It keeps my modifiers but not the materials.

I need to solve this problem because It is an important part of my worflow and I will have to work with differents peoples & we need to find a way to update easily the datas.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I figured out that you were talking about editing the original alembic file, then re-importing it. Have you tried messing around with the content of the material slots to just switch materials easily?

Comment: Yes, sorry if it wasn't clear. I need to edit and import again my alembics without loosing the materials assignements, modifiers & positions. 
I tried to link a blender file with an embed Alembic but it doesn't work for the materials unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried attaching the material slots to the object data block and then re-importing the alembic but keeping the old object and changing it to use the new mesh data block?

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I didn't think about this (I never used Data blocks yet). I changed the datablock in the Object Property/Browse mesh data. The mesh changes well but I lose the shading properties.

Comment: OK, in the materials tab, there’s a little setting for each material slot whether it links the slot to the object data or the mesh data. I haven’t played with this very much, but it might help you. I’m more just telling you something to experiment with here.

Comment: I tried both with Data & Objects but it doesn't work. I can change the alembic and keep the modifiers, but not the materials, it looks like a bug and really don't know how to avoid it. Anyway, I just have to update the materials for the moment, I will live with it for the moment and will search again in a few weeks when it will be more vital. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way I found was to move the original alembic, close the project and reopen it, then you get an error.

Then you only need to update the file location of one object and all the other objects that have the same error will be updated as well.

Comment: Thank you, it will help on my actual project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but one option would be to re-link the materials by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> > *Link Materials*